# Can a Dream's camera really zoom from the camera app?

Tags: camera, htc-dream, zooming

I upgraded my HTC Dream to CM6.1, and the camera app now has a zoom option.  Is this a real zoom, or just a digital blow-up of the image?  I'm guessing the latter.

Comment: see also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/in-camera-apps-is-zoom-a-digital-zoom-or-an-optical-zoom/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no mention of physical zoom on the [HTC Dream specification](http://www.htc.com/www/product/dream/specification.html) page. (To my knowledge no Android camera has that.)